# How to fix Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:27)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-leaflet

```
index.js:1 ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|  
index.js:1 ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/pane.js 2:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export function withPane(props, context) {
>   const pane = props.pane ?? context.pane;
|   return pane ? { ...props,
|     pane
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
index.js:1 ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/layer.js 8:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:46)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
```